# Test for successful message on toast in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I am working on Xamarin forms application where I'm using [Toast.Forms.Plugin](https://github.com/EgorBo/Toasts.Forms.Plugin)

to show the popups when ever there is invalid login. I'm not able to understand how to write the UI test case to test negative login scenario to check the text on that toast as there is no XAML element. Please find the screenshot.
[image]

I want to test that Some success text is available or not.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? If you are doing the login, then you are showing the toast and you set the text yourself.

Answer (score 2):

In Xamarin Android you can show as usual like

```
Toast.MakeText(this,"toast message", ToastLength.Long).Show();
```

In Xamarin iOS you have to use custom designed UIView with animation to achieve the same effect

```
public void ShowToast(String message, UIView view)
    {
        UIView residualView = view.ViewWithTag(1989);
        if (residualView != null)
            residualView.RemoveFromSuperview();

        var viewBack = new UIView(new CoreGraphics.CGRect(83, 0, 300, 100));
        viewBack.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Black;
        viewBack.Tag = 1989;
        UILabel lblMsg = new UILabel(new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 20, 300, 60));
        lblMsg.Lines = 2;
        lblMsg.Text = message;
        lblMsg.TextColor = UIColor.White;
        lblMsg.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;
        viewBack.Center = view.Center;
        viewBack.AddSubview(lblMsg);
        view.AddSubview(viewBack);
        roundtheCorner(viewBack);
        UIView.BeginAnimations("Toast");
        UIView.SetAnimationDuration(3.0f);
        viewBack.Alpha = 0.0f;
        UIView.CommitAnimations();
    }
```